# Day of month not an integer

Tags: bash, date

I am making an adjustment [a bash script of mine](http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com.au/2015/09/date-time-stamps-in-bash-with-ordinal.html) to output the ordinal part (st, nd, rd, th) of a day of month. I am trying to adjust it to be used within a date pattern in the `date` command.

Here is a simple test to determine if day of month from `date` command is an int:

```
dayOfMonth=$(date +"%d") && [[ ${dayOfMonth} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo ${dayOfMonth} is an int || echo ${dayOfMonth} is NOT an int
```

Output is as I expect

```
01 is an int
```

Now I put that code into a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ ${1} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo ${1} is an int || echo ${1} is NOT an int
```

Seems OK:

```
dateTest.sh 12
12 is an int
```

But when I try to use it within a `date` command, the script is giving me conflicting output. `echo` sees `12` but the test is seeing `%2`

```
date --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"`dateTest.sh %d`"
12 is NOT an int
```

To clarify my purpose, the end result of the script will be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=$(date +"%d")

if [ $# -ge 1 ] ; then
   n=$1
   if ! [[ $n =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
      echo Arg dateInteger [$dateInteger] must be an integer.
      exit 1
   fi
fi

if [ $n -ge 11 -a $n -le 13 ] ; then
  echo "th"
else
 case $(( $n%10 )) in
 1)
   echo st
   ;;
 2)
   echo nd
   ;;
 3)
   echo rd
   ;;
 *)
   echo th
   ;;
 esac
fi
```

So that I can it like this:

```
date --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"%A, %d`dateTest.sh %d` of %B %Y, %I:%M:%S %p"
```

which would output

```
Tuesday, 12th of June 2012, 07:21:22 AM
```

Finished script re-write. Thanks to input from @GordonDavisson, I completed my script re-write: http://pastebin.com/xZ1afqqC. Now it either outputs just the ordinal from an integer, or will output a fully formatted date where you can use standard format strings from `date` with the addition of "%O" for the ordinal.

Comment: `dayOfMonth=$(date +"%d") && [ "$dayOfMonth" -eq "$dayOfMonth" >/dev/null 2>&1 ] && echo ${dayOfMonth} is an int || echo ${dayOfMonth} is NOT an int`

Comment: If added in the script like this it works....   odate=`date --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"%d"`

[[ $odate =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo $odate is an int || echo $odate is NOT an int

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin - good addition.

Comment: @thehappymamba - sorry, that is not what I want to do. My script will default the argument as `n=$(date +"%d")`, but I want the script to be able to override that default with an argument - so that I could use it as part of an external `date` command. I.e. default to `n=$(date +"%d")` but if an argument is given, verify that the arg is an int.

Comment: Ok thanks for the update!  This worked for me but not sure if it is what you want (back ticks around the date command to the end - stack overflow  cut it off):  ./dateTest.sh `date --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22' +%d`
12 is an int

Comment: Hi @thehappymamba, no, what I want to achieve is the ability to use the script *inside the date pattern*. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing things in the wrong order -- you have to turn "%d" into an integer (the day of the month) *before* passing it to your script, not after. Consider the command:

```
date --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"`dateTest.sh %d`"
```

What this does is run `dateTest.sh %d`, i.e. it passes "%d" as the argument to your script. The script naturally outputs "%d is not an int". This is then used as the format string for the `date` command, i.e. `date --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"%d is not an int"`. The `date` command replaces the "%d" part with the day number, and leaves the rest alone, giving "12 is not an int".

In order to make this work, you have to get the day number first, then pass that to your script. Something like this:

```
dateTest.sh "$(date --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"%d")"
```

Unfortunately, your end result script also wants a bunch of other date formatting done that *can't* be passed to the dateTest script. I think in that case it'd be best to do it in stages:

```
dayWithSuffix="$(dateTest.sh "$(date --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"%d")")"
date --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"%A, $dayWithSuffix of %B %Y, %I:%M:%S %p"
```

BTW, several general scripting suggestions:

- Send error/debug output to stderr, not stdout, so it doesn't get confused with the script's regular output (part of the problem here). For example, `echo "${1} is NOT an int" >&2`
- Speaking of which, put strings that contain variables in double-quotes (as I did in that last example) to avoid weird misparsing of whitespace, wildcards, etc. Your result script, for example, contains `echo Arg dateInteger [$dateInteger] must be an integer.` -- you probably don't realize that under certain circumstances the `[$dateInteger]` part will be replaced by a list of filenames.
- Finally, use `$( ... )` instead of backquotes. In most cases they're equivalent, but the parenthesis version is easier to read and avoids some weird parsing oddities of the contents. Notice how I nested two such expressions in the assignment to `dayWithSuffix`? That's much trickier to get right with backquotes.

Comment: Thanks for this - now that I see it, it's obvious - I was catching "%d", outputting "%d" and the date command was using it. Wow. :) Thanks for the other tips too - I will keep them in mind.